# How to append sql to Entity Framework query

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How to append raw sql e.g. condition to entity framework linq query?

I'm open to all suggestions so it's not mandatory to append it to linq query main point is to e.g. filter by adding some custom sql to query overall.

Comment: Just to follow up on my research and recent response from EF team, yes you can use interceptors to do the job but it's very hard to do so not to mention impractical and inefficient.It will be good to have field expressions to simplify the injections like some other ORM that I use have.

Answer (score 0):

Using IQueryable we can append the condition on the Linq to entity query.

```
 private IQueryable<Customer> FilterList(IQueryable<Customer> customer, List<string> filter, string filterValue)
            {
                IQueryable<Customer> query = new List<Customer>().AsQueryable();            

                if (filter == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterValue))
                {
                    return customer;
                }

                var filterLower = filter.First().ToLower();

                filterValue = filterValue.ToLower();

                if (filterLower.Contains("retail") || (filterLower.Contains("distributor"))
                {
                    return customer.Where(x => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Retail) && x.Retail.Contains(filterValue)) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Distributor) && x.Distributor.Contains(filterValue)));
                }

                if (filterLower.Contains("retail"))
                {
                    query = customer.Where( x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Distributor) && x.Distributor.Contains(filterValue));
                }

                if (filterLower.Contains("distributor"))
                {
                    query = customer.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Retail) && x.Retail.Contains(filterValue)).Union(query);
                }
               return query;
    }
```

Comment: Yes that would be the case if I know that this is Customer object, I was thinking more about putting raw sql in place of a field.